# Best way to learn Iphone Development

Tags: xcode

Hope all of you doing great. I am new in Iphone development using xcode and want to know the best way of learning?

thanks

Comment: btw, this has been asked a million times.  the first thing any good programmer has to learn is how to use a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to go straight to the source.

Apple have some great docs that are worth reading.

For example - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514